# How to run command with more quotes, brackets and rerdirections in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have bash command:

```bash
cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += { "Modules\\": "Modules/" }' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json
```

But in ansible I get more errors.

```yaml
---

- name: modules autoload
  shell: |
    cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += { "Modules\\": "Modules/" }' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json
```

```bash
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload.\"psr-4\" += { \"Modules\\\\\": \"Modules/\" }' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json", "delta": "0:00:00.001537", "end": "2023-03-13 01:06:28.268890", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2023-03-13 01:06:28.267353", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

or

```yaml
---

- name: modules autoload
  command: |
    cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += { "Modules\\": "Modules/" }' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json
```

```bash
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["cat", "<<<", "$(jq", "--indent", "4", ".autoload.\"psr-4\" += { \"Modules\\\\\": \"Modules/\" }", "me/composer.json)", ">", "me/composer.json"], "delta": "0:00:00.001982", "end": "2023-03-13 01:08:33.239162", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-03-13 01:08:33.237180", "stderr": "cat: unrecognized option '--indent'\nTry 'cat --help' for more information.", "stderr_lines": ["cat: unrecognized option '--indent'", "Try 'cat --help' for more information."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the file for testing

```yaml
shell> cat me/composer.json 
{"autoload": {"psr-4": {"X": "Y"}}}
```

The command

```bash
shell> cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += {"Modules": "Modules"}' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json.new
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> cat me/composer.json.new 
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "X": "Y",
            "Modules": "Modules"
        }
    }
}
```

To run this command in the Ansible module [*shell*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#ansible-builtin-shell-module-execute-shell-commands-on-targets):

- Put the run string into a [*block*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-8-block-style-productions) in a variable. This way you get rid of one level of quotation.
- Use the [*single-quoted style*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style). This way only the single quote `'` must be escaped.
- By default the module *shell* runs the command through [*/bin/sh*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#synopsis). Change the executable to *bash*, or another shell you tested the command with.
- By default the command is executed in the home directory of the effective user. Change it to the absolute path where you store the file(s). In the example below, running on the localhost, the directory *me* is in the playbook directory. See the special variable [*playbook_dir*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables).

```yaml
    - shell:
        cmd: '{{ cmd }}'
        chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
        executable: /usr/bin/bash
      vars:
        cmd: >-
          cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += {"Modules": "Modules"}' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json.new
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out:
    changed: true
    cmd: 'cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 ''.autoload."psr-4" += {"Modules": "Modules"}'' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json.new'
    delta: '0:00:00.051676'
    end: '2023-03-13 01:44:07.508255'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-03-13 01:44:07.456579'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []
```

---

The new file was created

```yaml
shell> cat me/composer.json.new 
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "X": "Y",
            "Modules": "Modules"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - shell:
        cmd: echo $0 $PWD $USER
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - shell:
        cmd: echo $0 $PWD $USER
        chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
        executable: /usr/bin/bash
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
  
    - shell:
        cmd: '{{ cmd }}'
        chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}"
        executable: /usr/bin/bash
      vars:
        cmd: >-
          cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += {"Modules": "Modules"}' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json.new
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the detailed answer. In short: use shell + cmd, and redeclare executable.

```shell:
    cmd: |
      cat <<< $(jq --indent 4 '.autoload."psr-4" += { "Modles\\": "Modules/" }' me/composer.json) > me/composer.json
    executable: /usr/bin/bash
```